# isotope height not calculated right tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, tablet

So my problem: I'm using [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and I'm having a height issue. It doesn't calculate the correct height on a tablet/iPad - it gets all crumbled up at the top). Desktop and smartphones are working fine.

This is my code for isotope:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        transitionDuration: '0.7s'
    });

    $('.isotope-filters').on('click', 'a', function () {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: filterValue
        });

        // active state
        var active =
                $(this),
                activeClass = active.data('filter'),
                parentFilters = active.closest('.isotope-filters');

        if (active.hasClass('selected')) {
            return false;
        }

        parentFilters.find('a').removeClass('active');
        active.addClass('active');
        parentFilters.next().find('.isotope').addBack('.isotope').isotope({
            filter: active.attr('data-filter')
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```